# Programming Serial Ports in Linux using Device::SerialPorts

Tags: linux, perl, serial-port

I am trying to communicate with a embedded system using a communication port COM0 which is ttyS0 in linux. I tried another software on Windows and it seems to be able to communicate properly with the port. I tried using this code, but right at the very first line I get an error.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Device::SerialPort;


die "Cannot Open Serial Port\n" unless my $PortObj = new Device::SerialPort ("/dev/ttyS0");
```

Also is there another easier way to communicate with the serial port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need code that looks like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Device::SerialPort;

die "Cannot Open Serial Port\n"
   unless my $PortObj = Device::SerialPort->new(
      $^O eq "MSWin32" ? "com1" : "/dev/ttyS0"
   );
```

Note, I do not know if `com1` is the right serial port for your code, but I think you need something like that.  If you have many more platforms you need to deal with a hash may be a better option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Device::SerialPort;

my %port_name = (
    MSWin32 => "com1",
    linux   => "/dev/ttyS0",
);

die "I don't know what serial port to use on $^O\n"
    unless exists $port_name{$^O};    

die "Cannot Open Serial Port\n"
   unless my $PortObj = Device::SerialPort->new($port_name{$^O});
```

Comment: Oh okay, that worked. The main problem was another application was hogging the serial port so it couldn't connect.